# Single page version of docs

Tags: help-system

I would like to read the Vim user guide and reference docs and man pages on my Kindle Paperwhite. Does anyone know of a single page web readable version of the docs? Or even a PDF?

Https://vim.help is more readable than https://Vimhelp.org but it only contains the user guide. And neither of them has a single page version that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/) contains lots of useful links, including to some out-of-date PDFs.

[vi-improved.ord](https://www.vi-improved.org/vimusermanual.pdf) (run by some of our compatriots here) also has a slightly newer PDF that Google found, though I don’t think they actually mention it on the site.

[Nathan Grigg](https://nathangrigg.com/vimhelp/) maintains a very up-to-date version, apparently. They’ve [shared the conversion code](https://github.com/nathangrigg/vimhelppdf) so it’s possible to DIY.

Comment: Thanks, these are all great.